# List circular group membership from active directory

Tags: algorithm, scripting, vbscript

We have 40K+ groups in our active directory and we are increasingly facing problem of circular nested groups which are creating problems for some applications.

Does anyone know how to list down the full route through which a circular group membership exists ?

e.g.

```
G1 --> G2 --> G3 --> G4 --> G1
```

How do I list it down.

Comment: What do you mean by "List down"?  Are you looking to create a list of nested groups for each group in manner which doesn't break if a circular reference exists OR are you simply searching for groups that are involved ina circular loop?

Comment: I want to search for nested circular groups and list how they are nested.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.rlmueller.net/CircularNested.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a modified version of this code should do the trick.  Check out the book as well of course, its an excellent desk resource I refer to often.

```
' This VBScript code prints the nested membership of a group.

' ---------------------------------------------------------------
' From the book "Active Directory Cookbook" by Robbie Allen
' ISBN: 0-596-00466-4
' ---------------------------------------------------------------

' ------ SCRIPT CONFIGURATION ------
strGroupDN = "<GroupDN>"  ' e.g. cn=SalesGroup,ou=Groups,dc=rallencorp,dc=com
' ------ END CONFIGURATION ---------

strSpaces  = " "
set dicSeenGroupMember = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Wscript.Echo "Members of " & strGroupDN & ":"
DisplayMembers "LDAP://" & strGroupDN, strSpaces, dicSeenGroupMember

Function DisplayMembers ( strGroupADsPath, strSpaces, dicSeenGroupMember)

   set objGroup = GetObject(strGroupADsPath)
   for each objMember In objGroup.Members
      Wscript.Echo strSpaces & objMember.Name
      if objMember.Class = "group" then
         if dicSeenGroupMember.Exists(objMember.ADsPath) then
            Wscript.Echo strSpaces & "   ^ already seen group member " & _
                                     "(stopping to avoid loop)"
         else
            dicSeenGroupMember.Add objMember.ADsPath, 1
            DisplayMembers objMember.ADsPath, strSpaces & " ", _
                           dicSeenGroupMember
         end if
      end if
   next

End Function
```

Comment: That doesn't help much as it provides the nested membership information, which is fine, but doesn't tell whether there is circular reference involved, if there is then through which group membership.

In search for answer, I found a technique called Depth First Search for graph traversal, it was mentioned in pseudo code, so I implemented it in Vbscript, but it doesn;t work well. I am currently in process of implementing it in another language like Python.